# How to know if I can use the Windows command "mklink"?

Tags: vbscript

I'm writing an install vbscript that must to run on Windows servers or workstations. Some servers are not able to run this internal command (Windows Server 2003). In my script I'd like to know if the system is able to run "mklink" or not (to create symbolic links).
I try to get the return code of the "run command" but it doesn't help :

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
rc = oShell.Run("cmd /C mklink", 0, True)
rc = oShell.Run("cmd /C mklinks", 0, True)
```

1) "mklink" exists, it display its help message : rc = 1
2) "mklinks" doesn't exist : rc = 1

If I try manually these commands in the console and display %ERRORLEVEL%,
 
1) I get "1"
2) I get "9009" ! Yesss, but I get "1" for the return code of the Run method.

I tried also the "Exec" method of the shell object, but I get "0" in the two cases.

An idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retrieving the exit code of the `cmd` instance, not the exit code of the executed command. To get the exit code of the command you can try with

```
rc = oShell.Run("cmd /v /c mklink & exit !errorlevel!", 0, True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Works great ! Before, I tried with ... & exit %ERRORLEVEL% but without success.

Comment: @P.Debrabant, normal variable expansion (`%var%`) is done at parse time, before the command has been executed. In this case you need delayed expansion enabled (`/v`) and syntax changed to `!var!` to indicate to the parser that the variable expansion must be delayed until the command is going to be executed.